# Paypal Smart Button: how to redirect to a PHP page after successfull payment?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm trying to integrate paypal payment into my web site.

EDIT:

After a sucessfull payment I want to redirect to a PHP page to manipulate payment data, for instance: Saving to db transaction and payment id, payer email , send email etc.

So this is my "onApprove" function:

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {

  var EXECUTE_URL = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/actions/paymentsuccess.php';

  return fetch(EXECUTE_URL, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      paymentID: data.paymentID,
      payerID: data.payerID,
      payerEmail: data.payerEmail,
      payerName: data.payerName,
      payerPhone: data.payerPhone
    })
  });
},
```

How to call a PHP page (maybe with a POST ) and pass all payment data, and elaborate that page (i don't need to stay to the payment page) ?

Thanks

Comment: is the above code of yours javascript or php? who is calling this `onApprove`?

Comment: It Is javascript based on Paypal sdk.
I want to 'pass' data structure to another PHP page

Comment: is your paymentsuccess.php script actually imports these data in your DB or is it just presenting them? while the paypal callback calls a hidden script to validate the transaction?

Comment: paymentsuccess.php must do 2 things: record data in mysql database, send confirmation email.. finally redirect to another 'success.html' page. I don't want to call "hidden" script

Answer (score 2):

If you need to *do something*, you should do it inside the 'EXECUTE_URL' on your server (or with more current integrations, a capture URL) This is where any important business task should be *done.*

But if you want to then redirect the user some resulting point (not to "do something"), this should take place after the fetch, and only if the fetch is successful. You will need to add a JS redirect yourself.

---

So basically, add `.then()` code that deals with the fetch's response.

For current integrations (which use a capture, not an execute), here is an example implementation that parses a fetch response: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Ok, so i'm doing wrong using FETCH function. 
I just want to post result to a php page that "do something" and this page will show a success or failure message .. 
So i think i've not to use FETCH. Is it true ?

Comment: No, it's not true. Add your `.then()` to the fetch and do your redirect in there as appropriate

Comment: But I want a redirect to a PHP, passing payment data (email, paymentid, etc) . So in that PHP i do "something" (database update etc), and finally go to a success page. I think Fetch is not the correct way...

Comment: The things should be done in the fetch. The redirect should be done after the fetch. This is not complicated.

Comment: Ok, but why I can't redirect from inside https://www.mywebsite.com/actions/paymentsuccess.php ? I want to do "thing" in paymentsuccess.php and , inside there redirect to success.php if all is ok , or failure.php if failed. So my question is: i don't want to use fetch, but want to pass paypal payment data to a php (using post or get?) .. how ?

Comment: Don't do the thing you want to do. It's not reliable. All information should be in the fetch. On page load, retrieve anything you need from your database.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. But After a payment, i need to create database record, send confirmation email etc. I've to do in a PHP page AFTER payment so i know payer email  etc.

Comment: The fetch will trigger the capture action on your server. Do it then.

Answer (score 2):

if by the way you are using paypal sdk then you should really follow the documentation [about confirmation page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/confirmation-page/) and present the user info that you want on the same page that already has the paypal's sdk objects loaded

```
onApprove: function (data, actions) {

    // Get the order details
    return actions.order.get().then(function (orderDetails) {

      // Show a confirmation using the details from orderDetails
      // Then listen for a click on your confirm button

      document.querySelector('#confirm-button')
        .addEventListener('click', function () {

          // Capture the transaction funds
          return actions.order.capture().then(function () {
            // Show a confirmation to the buyer
          });
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: How I understand it, this confirmation example doesn't answer the question because it's asking about redirecting the user to a page AFTER payment, and this is about a confirmation page BEFORE payment.